# PHP - fopen(): failed to open stream: Permission denied on a mac?

Tags: php, fopen

I can't get it to work and create a simple file in the same directory.

I'm using a Mac and  text editor is Sublime Text, and the php version is 5.5.30.

This is the code I'm executing:

```
<?php  
  $file = fopen( 'data/data.txt' , 'w' );
  if( $file ) {
    echo 'The file is open';
    fclose( $file );
  }else{
    echo 'The file could not be open.';
  }
?>
```

This is the error generated in the browser:

*Warning: fopen(data/data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php_class/class_examples/open_and_close.php on line 17*

I searched online for an answer to the error and this is the solution I got to fix the problem:

Open the terminal, go to the directory where the script is located and enter the following command

```
sudo chmod 777 open_and_close.php
```

Now I did all of this and I'm still getting the same error.
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. check permissions on `data` folder itself;
2. check filepath is it correct;

Comment: You need to `chmod 0777` or `chmod +r` on the file you need to open, not on the php file that you're executing

Comment: You need to `chmod` the file you're trying to fopen, not the .php file itself.

Comment: That worked, thank you @mitkosoft

Comment: The permissions on the data folder was the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to run the command for : `data/data.txt` and not for `open_and_close.php`

`sudo chmod 777 data/data.txt`